# When i am updating my symfony 4.4 to 6.4 then getting entity issue

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, symfony6

**I am getting issue on symfony version 4.4 to 6.4.**

[error] Migration DoctrineMigrations\Version20240221055325 failed during Execution. Error: "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'FK_55C81AEFA76ED395' are incompatible."

Comment: adding the Version20240221055325.php code and the initial user entity at 4.4 in this post would help ...